# How to force fluid Vimeo iframe to auto-center vertically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I'm trying to modify the popular fluid jQuery script to be able to auto-center a vimeo video vertically ( like [this](http://themes.evgenyfireform.com/wp-jad/) ) , but can't figure it out.

Don't want to see any black bars, some horizontal cropping would be fine.

Here is my code so far:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="videoWrapper">
        <iframe class="js-resize" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/80836225?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;autoplay=1" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    height: 100%;
    width:auto;
}
.videoWrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}

.videoWrapper iframe,
.videoWrapper embed,
.videoWrapper object {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}


html, body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

**JS**

```
// jQuery 1.6.2

// Find all YouTube videos
var $allVideos = $("iframe[src^='http://player.vimeo.com'], iframe[src^='http://www.youtube.com']"),

    // The element that is fluid width
    $fluidEl = $("body");

// Figure out and save aspect ratio for each video
$allVideos.each(function() {

  $(this)
    .data('aspectRatio', this.height / this.width)

    // and remove the hard coded width/height
    .removeAttr('height')
    .removeAttr('width');

});

// When the window is resized
$(window).resize(function() {

  var newWidth = $fluidEl.width();

  // Resize all videos according to their own aspect ratio
  $allVideos.each(function() {

    var $el = $(this);
    $el
      .width(newWidth)
      .height(newWidth * $el.data('aspectRatio'));

  });

// Kick off one resize to fix all videos on page load
}).resize();
```

Comment: Have you noticed you're missing a closing tag to the `.container` element?

Comment: Thank you, fixed! Black bars are still there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In your CSS set height of

```
videoWrapper iframe {height:XXXXpx;}
```

where XXXX will be the desire height value in pixels

then add to

```
videoWrapper iframe {margin-top:-XXpx;}
```

where -XXpx is half the value of your full height

and finally in your videowarpper iframe set:

```
videoWrapper iframe {position:absolute; top:50%;}
```

So you will end with:

```
.videoWrapper {
position: relative;
height: 100%;
width: auto;
}

.videoWrapper iframe,
.videoWrapper embed,
.videoWrapper object {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: XXXXpx;
margin-top: -XXpx;
left: 0;
top: 50%;
}
```

This should set the top margin of your object to the vertical center of itself and then position that margin (now in the center of the object) to be precisely in the center of the screen.

I haven't tried it but have a go and please let me know if it helps!